# How to calculate points on a line at intervals

Tags: java, math, points

I am coding a game and want a projectile to go from one location to the next moving at intervals every frame.

I've been playing around with the slope-intercept method of determining things and I'm getting close, but I am stuck.

Here is my code so far:

```
animationFrame = refresh;
    double x, y, xPerF; //Values for drawing
    double m, b; //Value for slope and y-intercept
    double x1, x2, y1, y2; //Values for the targets
    x1 = getCenterX();
    x2 = Canvas.target[shotTarget].getCenterX();
    y1 = getCenterY();
    y2 = Canvas.target[shotTarget].getCenterY();
    xPerF = Point2D.distance(x1, y1, x2, y2)/animationSpeed;
    //Calculate slope
    if(x2>x1) m = (y2-y1)/(x2-x1);
    else if(x2<x1) m = (y1-y2)/(x1-x2);
    else m = 0;
    //Calculate the y-intercept
    b = m * x1 - y1;
    if(b<0) b = -b + Canvas.myHeight;
    else {
        b -= Canvas.myHeight;
        if(b<0) b = -b;
    }
    //Calculate the x value
    if(x1>x2) x = x1 - (xPerF * animationFrame);
    else if(x1<x2) x = x1 + (xPerF * animationFrame);
    else x = x1;
    //Calculate the y value
    if(m!=0) y = (m * x + b) - Canvas.myHeight;
    else {
        if(y1>y2) y = y1 - (xPerF * animationFrame);
    else y = y1 + (xPerF * animationFrame);
    }
    g.fillOval((int) x - 15, (int) y - 15, 30, 30);
    //Debugging
    System.out.println("Frame " + animationFrame + " of " + animationSpeed + " | " + y + " = " + m + " * " + x + " + " + b + " | at speed of " + xPerF);
```

## Updated

I expect the animation to end at the target location, but it always either overshoots or is right on target. It mainly overshoots when the target is pretty kind of straight above the tower, give or take a few x co-ordinates. I have worked this out to be a quadrant 1 x-y plane and I believe the problem I have now lies with how I am calculating my slope. Thanks!

## Outdated

Here is a mini applet to demonstrate: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fCTFJzulY1fcBUmdV6AXOd7Ol1g9B3lo/view?usp=sharing

Click on each target to target it

Comment: Maybe you can prepare reproducable example?

Comment: @Antoniossss What do you mean?

Comment: I mean create piece of code that I can actually run locally and maybe try to fix it.

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel?  Look into a physics engine, such as box2d.

Comment: @Herbert Marshall I am coding this from scratch. I'm using EclipseIDE.

Comment: @Antoniossss I gave you the code for the math and the drawing portion, what more do you need? The target and the source of the projectile are classes which extend java.awt.Rectangle if that helps.

Comment: I want to copy-paste and hit run to see the effect.

Comment: Luca usually providing a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) greatly improves your chances of getting a good response here. The amount of efforts required to try your code and see what exactly is going wrong is a barrier that people have to overcome to help you. The lower the barrier - the more people are inclined to help.

Comment: I understand. I'll do my best to make an applet that can correctly replicate my issue

Comment: @Antoniossss Your applet is there. All of the problems I encounter exist in that project. The source code is available and a runnable jar file is as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Answer

I figured it out. Instead of calculating the coordinates with slope-intercept method, I simply calculated the intervals I would have to increment y and x per frame and incremented them based on the frame of the animation.

```
double x, y, xPerF, yPerF; //Values for drawing
double x1, x2, y1, y2; //Values for the targets
x1 = getCenterX();
x2 = Canvas.target[shotTarget].getCenterX();
y1 = getCenterY();
y2 = Canvas.target[shotTarget].getCenterY();
xPerF = (Math.max(x1, x2) - Math.min(x1, x2))/animationSpeed;
yPerF = (Math.max(y1, y2) - Math.min(y1, y2))/animationSpeed;
if(x1>x2) x = x1 - xPerF * animationFrame;
else if(x1<x2) x = x1 + xPerF * animationFrame;
else x = x1;
if(y1>y2) y = y1 - yPerF * animationFrame;
else if(y1<y2) y = y1 + yPerF * animationFrame;
else y = y1;
g.fillOval((int) x - 15, (int) y - 15, 30, 30);
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe your approach is fundamentally flawed. It is prone to rounding errors which might be a source for overshoots. It is also hard to make work well under real world where your application is not the only one so CPU might be in high demand and some frames might be skipped, and so on. The better approach is to use time rather than frames as the main driver of the events. Your main method `drawScene` accepts current time as one of its arguments. When any animation starts, you save the time when it started. Then, the job becomes much easier. For example for linear animation it would be something like this:

```
double animationPart = (currentTime - animationStartTime) / totalAnimationDuration;
// fix rounding error
if (animationPart > 1.0)
    animationPart = 1.0; 

double xCur = xStart * (1.0 - animationPart) + xEnd * animationPart;
double yCur = yStart * (1.0 - animationPart) + yEnd * animationPart;
```

P.S. the "time" doesn't have to be real time, it might be some other "game time" if it somehow makes more sense but still this approach is IMHO much easier to implement correctly.

---

## Update

I'd say that the overall code quality is rather bad. Concerns are badly separated, there are a lot of [magic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)), and global static things. For example, having to two bullets in flight will be not easy to implement in this code.

There are also some real bugs in animation code. Some obvious bugs are:

1. `xPerF` is calculated wrongly. You divide the Euclidean distance instead of just difference in the X-coordinate.
2. Logic for the `y` is flawed. At least you should add `m * (x - x1)` instead of `m * x`. But it still won't cover the case of a vertical shoot (i.e. the case when the X-coordinate is not changed at all). If you want to go this way, you should use `xPerF` ***and*** `yPerF` and get rid of the `m` and the related `if`'s.

This might or might not fix the animation issues (at list you still will have a potential for rounding errors). I'd still say that changing your `shoot` to something like

```
public void shootTarget(int target) {
    shotTarget = target;
    shotTime = animationFrame;
}
```

and then using

```
double animationPart = ((double) (animationFrame - shotTime)) / animationSpeed;
```

as suggested above is a better way. Note: this is only a stub because in your real code you for some reason regularly assign `0` to `refresh` and thus to `animationFrame` so it won't work that easy.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have a few questions though; one, what is the totalAnimationDuration? Two, what would be the current and start time? And three, what's a rounding error?

Comment: Also, I understand the usage of time rather than frames, but everything else in my program is based on frames. So, if one frame is skipped, the result actually is that the program appears to slow down. I will definitely consider using times in the future, but I do not wish to restructure my entire code to accommodate for one function which uses time. If you could post something that has to do with frames, that would be much appreciated

Comment: I have actually been working on this and have calculated a y-intercept changing mathematical values to simulate quadrant 1 of the x-y plane. And I assign 0 to refresh because the object shooting is a tower in a tower defense game that runs on the refresh variable. I am editing the code given in the OP.

Comment: Also, I would like to know what you mean by rounding error. P.S., the animation variable is only pertinent to the shooting and is based on the shooting progress of the tower itself so as to provide consistent visual feedback between the firing and the damage.